# Can we launch the android application every time we open it in the mobile

Tags: android

When I closed my app and re-opened it in the mobile,it is opening with the same page which I closed with. But my requirement is that, when I close my app and re-open it ,it should start from the beginning(launched) instead of starting from where I closed it.
Please help me solve this..

Comment: I am new to android, and please help me with sample code

Comment: If the user wants to start from the beginning they will 'back' out of the application. If they want to return to where they left off they will 'home' out of it. Let the user do what they want, otherwise you will see it in the number of uninstalls. Have you considered whether it is really necessary to restart the UI every time, or is it simply a part of the code that needs to be run every time the application is resumed, such as data that needs to be updated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Sushma](https://stackoverflow.com/users/919516/sushma)
How you can say your application closed or not ? On pressing **Back** button it won't close. You see android application/activity life cycle, then you will understand.

If you want to close your application on pressing Back button you have to close all activities in application, by implementing **onKeyDown** method, inside you have to call finish() for each activity.

One more thing don't post any questions immediately, first read documents and search in Internet, even you didn't got solution, then only use stackoverflow. If you post silly questions you will get negative votes and you will loss chance to post further questions.